# Avoiding slow evaluations in Manipulate when combining graphics with Show

Tags: plotting, graphics, performance-tuning, manipulate, dynamic

I want to figure out how to combine several graphics in manipulate such that only the ones that change are recomputed.

I looked into the tutorials on Advanced Manipulate, but couldn't figure out how to get this to work.
In the toy example below, I combine two graphics with `Show`. When I move the control for the point `p`, the `ContourPlot` also gets recomputed, which leads to a low-res drawing (in my actual example, the graphs are a lot more complex, so re-evaluating them, even when the relevant parameters don't change isn't an option). I tried using `Dynamic`, but couldn't find a solution that works. Any help highly appreciated!

```
Manipulate[
Show[ContourPlot[Cos[a x] + Cos[ a y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
  Graphics[Disk[p, 0.02]]],
 {{a, 10}, 0, 20},
 {p, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}
 ]
```

Answer (score 12):

#### TL;DR;

```
 Graphics[{
        Dynamic @ First @ plottingprocedure,
        Dynamic @ First @ anotherplottingprocedure,
        ...
      }, few options needed as we lost them above
    ]
```

#### Explanation

Independent interactive elements should not be gathered inside the same `Dynamic`.

And if they already are, due to an outer gui structure or, like here, simply because `Manipulate's` body acts like big `Dynamic` we can **nest Dynamic**. You can read more in:

- [tutorial / AdvancedDynamicFunctionality / Nesting Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) (*but read whole*)

How can we apply those rules to two plots that are supposed to be combined?

**Every** `*Plot*`/`Graph*` function evaluates to `Graphics[primitives, options]` which further typesets(?) to `GraphicsBox[primitivesBoxes, options]` and later `FrontEnd` takes care of rendering points/lines etc. Because it is done by the `FE`, primitives ([options too](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118646/5478)) can contain `Dynamic` elements as long as they wrap something that makes sense. That is primitives/directives/coordinates. So something like this will work:

```
Graphics @ Dynamic @ Disk[]
```

There is one but, `Graphics` can't contain `Graphics`:

```
Graphics @ Dynamic @ Graphics @ Disk[] (*pink box*)
```

so if we want to combine separate `Graphics` we need to extract their primitives (and options). Just by `First @ Graphics...`, as easy as that.

This is what you need:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {Dynamic @ First @ ContourPlot[Cos[a x] + Cos[a y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], 
   Dynamic @ First @ Graphics[Disk[p, 0.02]]
   }, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
 {{a, 10}, 0, 20}, 
 {p, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}
]
```

`Graphics[Disk[p, 0.02]]` could be whatever plotting function but in such simple case just `Disk[Dynamic @ p, 0.02]` will work.

More examples:

- [Rotating a contour plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104442/5478)
- [Performance issue of Manipulate with NSolve and Locator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134785/5478)

Also, notice that performance of locator drops as the `ContourPlot` gets more complicated, it is related to performance of graphics renderer (as opposed to recalculation issue we had before), there are some tricks to improve it too. Though it is not a major issue here:

- [Why does a heavy background slow LocatorPane from updating, even if only the locators are Dynamic?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43152/5478)
- [UI performance with large image data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127523/5478)

Comment: OK, you've convinced me. I am happy to learn something new about dynamic evaluation of graphics.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm glad I did, this is really something fundamental which should be included in docs as part of basic guidelines in dynamics. Unfortunately it is not.

Comment: BTW, you can get away with just `Dynamic @ Disk[p, 0.02]`

Comment: @m_goldberg correct, even `Disk[Dynamic@p, 0.02]` will do. Will change this later, with comments. Wanted to show a general way meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely, but I noticed that in Kuba's solution the axis disappear in the contour plot. I couldn't figure out how to avoid this. The simpler solution of just using Dynamic in front of p doesn't apply for the more complex example I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Beginner add `Frame->True` or whatever you want to `Graphics`. Sure it depends what we need to be `Dynamic`, FE understands `Dynamic` coordinates in graphics primitives so `Disk@Dynamic@p` is a solution but not a general one. All those details will come in comments I'm going to ad once I find time.

Comment: @Beginner explanation added, let me know if it is clear or if there are gaps in logic.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach which I use, is the tick method. The idea is to do the computation related to each control right there, using the second argument of dynamics. In this method, there is only one variable to track, which is the tick itself. I've described this method before in number of places. It is very flexible.

But with this method, one needs to initialize all the other variables for the initial display of Manipulate. I never found this an issue myself.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 Show[g1, g2],
 Grid[{
   {"a", Manipulator[Dynamic[a, {a = #;
        Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality"},
         g1 = ContourPlot[Cos[a x] + Cos[a y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
         ]; tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 20, .1}, ImageSize -> Small], 
    Spacer[3], Dynamic[a]}
   ,
   {"p", Slider2D[
     Dynamic[p, {p = #; g2 = Graphics[Disk[p, 0.02]]; 
        tick = Not[tick]} &], {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, ImageSize -> Small]}
   }],

 (*Initialization*)
 {{a, 10}, None},
 {{p, {0, 0}}, None},
 {{g1, ContourPlot[Cos[10 x] + Cos[10 y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]}, 
  None},
 {{g2, Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.02]]}, None},

 (*the tick is all what is needed to track*)
 {{tick, True}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```