# Superpose classic plot and plots with manipulate

Tags: plotting

I would like to superpose several plots :
- one which uses a Manipulate function with a parameter 
- and 4 plots which stays at the background and which are instanciations with four fix values of the parameter which is used in the Manipulate function.

Here you can find the function that i'm plotting :

```
AbsDepdimen[λ_][r_]:=1/Sqrt[(1 - r^2)^2 + 4 r^2 λ^2]
```

Here the code that i have tried without success :

```
Show[Manipulate[
  Plot[AbsDepdimen[\[Lambda]][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*FractionBox[\(X\), 
SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(st\)]]\)}], {\[Lambda], 0, 2}], 
 Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.0001][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*FractionBox[\(X\), 
SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(st\)]]\)}],
 Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.02][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*FractionBox[\(X\), 
SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(st\)]]\)}],
 Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.2][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*FractionBox[\(X\), 
SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(st\)]]\)}],
 Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.8][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*FractionBox[\(X\), 
SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(st\)]]\)}]]
```

Can you help me to find a way to combine Manipulate[Plot[]] and Plot[] (the classic one) in on the same graph as it is possible to do with Show function ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You need to do that inside that `Manipulate`. You may want to nest `Dynamic` to avoid recalculation of what is a static graphic. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148405/5478

Answer (score 1):

Kuba nailed it in his comment, but to unpack explicitly:

### Slow version with Show

```
Manipulate[Show[
    Plot[AbsDepdimen[\[Lambda]][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
      AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], X/Subscript[X, st]}],
   Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.0001][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
     AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], X/Subscript[X, st]}],
   Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.02][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
     AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], X/Subscript[X, st]}],
   Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.2][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
     AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], {Subscript[\[Omega], r], X/Subscript[X, st]}],
   Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.8][r], {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
     AxesLabel -> {Subscript[\[Omega], r], X/Subscript[X, st]}]], {\[Lambda], 0, 2}]
```

### Faster version with Graphics and Dynamic:

The only glitch here is you will possibly track Plot arguments
you haven't cared about before like AspectRatio etc, supplied at
the end of your Graphics statement.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{
     Dynamic@First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[\[Lambda]][r], {r, 0, 2}],
    Dynamic@First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.0001][r], {r, 0, 2}],
    Dynamic@First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.02][r], {r, 0, 2}],
    Dynamic@First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.2][r], {r, 0, 2}],
    Dynamic@First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.8][r], {r, 0, 2}]}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel ->  {Subscript[\[Omega], r], X/Subscript[X, st]}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], {\[Lambda], 0, 2}]
```

( I chose to use a Frame, but if you really prefer Axes the options are:

```
Axes -> True, AxesLabel ->  {Subscript[\[Omega], r], X/Subscript[X, st]}
```

)

---

**Update** Clarification due to Nasser's reasonable question.

As Nasser points out, it's not necessary to tag all the static guys with `Dynamic` (although I don't notice a penalty). In contrast I definitely run into a lag response if I don't tag the guys who are (potentially independently) changing under the manipulate. I suspect this is a result of Mathematica's effort to only update nested dynamic things when they update as documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#300598898).  Fair credit:  I only bothered reading any of this because of Kuba's fantastic [discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148405/avoiding-slow-evaluations-in-manipulate-when-combining-graphics-with-show).

To be explicit if only the first guy changes (as it does in the OP's example), but we don't want MMA to re-render everything else, seems we can get away with only nesting its dynamic:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{
     Dynamic@First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[\[Lambda]][r], {r, 0, 2}],
    First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.0001][r], {r, 0, 2}],
    First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.02][r], {r, 0, 2}],
    First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.2][r], {r, 0, 2}],
    First@Plot[AbsDepdimen[0.8][r], {r, 0, 2}]}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel ->  {Subscript[\[Omega], r], X/Subscript[X, st]}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], {\[Lambda], 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Why do you need to add `Dynamic` to `Dynamic@First@Plot` etc...? Why not just `First@Plot`?

Comment: Strictly speaking I guess to get the speed boost you only need the Dynamic on the thing that's getting manipulated.  Now I'm under the habit of applying generically when building something like this since usually not so many of the plots are static. But why Dynamic is helpful on the first guy, look at the very answer Kuba linked to: [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148412/51526).   I'll update my answer to reflect.