# Animating a Potential Function (eigenfunctions of Laplace's equation)

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, finite-element-method, animation, gui-construction

I have written the following `DynamicModule`. The idea is that you can change the boundary, calculate the eigenfunctions and then animate them. Here is the code:

```
DynamicModule[{pts, bdr = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, vals, 
  funs, n = 2, ar = False},
 pts = Table[{6, 6} + 3 {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 
    2 π - 2 π/10, 2 π/10}];
 bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Line[Join[pts, {pts[[1]]}]]];
 {vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ bdr, 6];
 ar = False;
 Column[{
   Row[{
     Button["Calculate",
      bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Line[Join[pts, {pts[[1]]}]]];
      {vals, funs} = 
       NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]}, 
        u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ bdr, 6]
      , ImageSize -> 1 72],
     Spacer[18],
     "Mode Number = ",
     Slider[Dynamic[n], {2, 6, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"],
     Spacer[18],
     Button["Toggle Animate", If[ar, ar = False, ar = True], 
      ImageSize -> 2 72]
     }],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
    Dynamic@Animate[Show[
       Graphics[{Line[Join[pts, {pts[[1]]}]]}, Frame -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}}, ImageSize -> 10 72],
       ContourPlot[funs[[n]] Cos[t], {x, y} ∈ bdr, 
        Axes -> None, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
        ColorFunction -> 
         Function[f, {Opacity[0.75], ColorData["TemperatureMap"][f]}]]
       ],
      {t, 0, 2 π}, AnimationRunning -> ar]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is mostly working. The problem is you cannot use the animation slider If you set up a boundary, calculate and then try and use it you get this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The locator has jumped to the animation slider controls. As a workaround I added the Toggle Animate button. This seems to work sometimes but not always. I am not clear what is wrong. How can I animate when requested.

The version is 11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)

Thanks for any help.

**Edit**

A minor point raised by Kuba. I am simulating an acoustic cavity. For this case the potential function is equivalent to the acoustic pressure while the gradient is equivalent to the acoustic particle velocity. Thus for the boundary conditions I have no Dirichlet boundary condition and use the fact that Mathematica assumes zero Neumann boundary conditions to make the acoustic velocity zero at the boundaries. To have, for example, a membrane simulation add the Dirichlet condition.

Comment: Maybe the title of the question is somewhat misleading. Still a cool app. You can use `DynamicModule` instead. There, you would have to wrap dymanic variables with `Dynamic`. The advantage is that `Dynamic` has a second, optional argument that lets you control when and how a change of the dynamic variable takes effect in the body of `DynamicModule`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher This is a `DynamicModule`. Are you suggesting a `DynamicModule` within a `DynamicModule`? I am familiar with using the second argument of Dynamic so I am not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: I think, I was suggesting to use a single `DynamicModule` instead of `Animate`. But you know, these dynamic programming things cause  headaches to me... Anyways, Kuba seems to have it solved for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fix is to move `Animate` outside of `LocatorPane`, but let's go couple of steps further:

- I turned Eigenvalues procedure into a function `calculate[]` to prevent code duplication
- The second argument of `Dynamic` in `Slider` and `LocatorPane` is used to neatly invoke `calculate[]`
- 'Nested `Dynamic`' and 'combining dynamic plots without `Show` ' tricks are used, read more in [148412](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148412/5478)
- `Plot3D` is added with a neat `ScalingTransform` trick which spares `Plot3D` recalculation if only `t` changes.

[image]

And a variation with `DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]`:

[image]

```
Deploy@DynamicModule[{pts, bdr = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   vals, funs, n = 2, ar = False, calculate},

  Animate[
   Column[{
     Row[{
       "Mode Number = ", 
       Slider[Dynamic[n, {Automatic, calculate[] &}], {2, 6, 1}, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"], Spacer[18],
       Button["Toggle Animate", If[ar, ar = False, ar = True], 
        ImageSize -> 2 72]
       }],
     Grid[{{
        LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, {Automatic, calculate[] &}],
         Graphics[{

           {Dynamic[
             First@ContourPlot[
               funs[[n]] Cos[t] , {x, y} \[Element] bdr, Axes -> None,
                Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
               ColorFunction -> 
                Function[f, {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][f]}],
               PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 50]]
             , TrackedSymbols :> {bdr, n, t}]
            },
           {FaceForm@None, EdgeForm@Thick, Polygon@Dynamic@pts}
           }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}}, 
          ImageSize -> 5 72
          ]
         ]
        ,
        Dynamic[
         Graphics3D[
          {GeometricTransformation[

            First@Plot3D[funs[[n]], {x, y} \[Element] bdr, 
              Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All
              ],
            ScalingTransform[{1, 1, Dynamic@Cos[t]}, {6, 6, 0}]
            ]
           }, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}, {-1, 1}}, 
          BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}, ImageSize -> 500, 
          ViewPoint -> {-6, -20, 20}]]
        }}]
     }]
   , {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AnimationRunning -> ar]
  ,
  Initialization :> (
    pts = 
     Table[{6, 6} + 3 {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
       2 \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]/10, 2 \[Pi]/10}];
    calculate[] := (
      bdr = Polygon@pts;
      {vals, funs} = 
       NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]}, 
        u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bdr, 6];


      );
    calculate[];
    )
  ]
```

Comment: Kuba thanks. A point that interested me was the quality of the `Graphics3D`. If the shape is changed while the animation is in progress then there is a poor quality plot (e.g. no mesh). However, if the animation is stopped and then a change made after a moment the quality plot appears and is maintained when the animation is started however fast it it run. I often have problems with poor quality animation because I get the poor quality image all the time not the high quality one.

Comment: @Hugh see [PerformanceGoal](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html), notice that during `t` animation the plot is smooth because I don't generate a plot3d's mesh again but just manipulate `GeometricTransform` parameter.

Comment: I have just been looking up`GeometricTransform` and examining your trick of using this to get the animation. I also notice that you have a `Dynamic` within a `Dynamic`. I guess Mathematica knows when to update each -something I am very unclear on; is there a tutorial on this?. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Hugh please see my edit and let me know if anything more should be commented on

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. We can remove The `Button["Toggle Animate"...` which did not work for me and does not work now. The `Animation` controls now work for this function. Thus also remove the `AnimationRunning`. Other usages that were new to me were `Automatic` in the `DynamicModule` (avoids `n=#`) , `ControlActive` (which is along the lines of `PerformanceGoal` and the use of `TrackedSymbols` within a Dynamic (I have only used this in a `DynamicModule`).