# Animating a potential function (eigenfunctions of Laplace's equation) - something has changed

Tags: dynamic, finite-element-method

I had this working with Kuba's help some time ago see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158416/12558) but something has changed. I am using version 13.0.

The animation lay out has changed to this configuration where the animation bar is occupying a row with the two graphics also in the row. It should be above the graphics.

[image]

Can anyone see what has changed and how to fix it?

The code is as follows.

```
    Deploy@DynamicModule[{pts, bdr = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   vals, funs, n = 2, calculate},
  
  Animate[Column[{
     Row[{
       Button["Reset", 
        pts = Table[{6, 6} + 
           3 {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
           2 \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]/10, 2 \[Pi]/10}];
        calculate[]],
       "   Mode Number = ", 
       Slider[Dynamic[n, {Automatic, calculate[] &}], {2, 6, 1}, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"]
       }],
     
     Row[{
       LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, {Automatic, calculate[] &}],
        Graphics[{{Dynamic[
            First@ContourPlot[funs[[n]] Cos[t], {x, y} \[Element] bdr,
              Axes -> None, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
              
              ColorFunction -> 
               Function[f, {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][f]}],
              PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 50]], 
            TrackedSymbols :> {bdr, n, t}]},
          {FaceForm@None, EdgeForm@Thick, Polygon@Dynamic@pts}},
         Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}}, 
         ImageSize -> 5 72]],
       
       Dynamic[
        Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[
           First@Plot3D[funs[[n]], {x, y} \[Element] bdr,
             Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All],
           ScalingTransform[{1, 1, Dynamic@Cos[t]}, {6, 6, 0}]]},
         PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}, {-1, 1}},
         BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}, ImageSize -> 5 72, 
         ViewPoint -> {-6, -20, 20}]]
       }]
     
     }],
   {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}],
  
  Initialization :> (
    pts = 
     Table[{6, 6} + 3 {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
       2 \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]/10, 2 \[Pi]/10}];
    calculate[] := (
      bdr = Polygon@pts;
      {vals, funs} = 
       NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]}, 
        u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bdr, 6];
      );
    
    calculate[];
    )
  
  ]
```

Comment: Try `ControlPlacement -> Top` in `Animate`, does it help?

Comment: Yes that seems to work. Thanks. All seems to have slowed down. I will look at that.

Comment: Yes, in a version I am testing it is unusable. The Countour plot became 40x slower at some point...

Comment: For a quick fix add `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` in the `ContourPlot` but the ux is still worse.

Comment: I suggest reporting this to WRI. Also, since the performance regression (well, is it just performance regression?) is a more serious problem, I suggest adding this to the body of question.

Comment: @xzczd Done and WRI confirmed an issue.

Comment: @kuba thanks. I use this in lectures each year.  This year it was disappointing.  Please let me know if it gets resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 Deploy@DynamicModule[{pts, bdr = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   vals, funs, n = 2, calculate}, Animate[
   
   Grid[{{Button["Reset", 
       pts = Table[{6, 6} + 
          3 {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
          2 \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]/10, 2 \[Pi]/10}];
       calculate[]], "Mode Number = ", 
      Slider[Dynamic[n, {Automatic, calculate[] &}], {2, 6, 1}, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"]},
     
     {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, {Automatic, calculate[] &}], 
       Graphics[{{Dynamic[
           First@ContourPlot[funs[[n]] Cos[t], {x, y} \[Element] bdr, 
             Axes -> None, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
             ColorFunction -> 
              Function[f, {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][f]}], 
             PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 50]], 
           TrackedSymbols :> {bdr, n, t}]}, {FaceForm@None, 
          EdgeForm@Thick, Polygon@Dynamic@pts}}, Frame -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}}, ImageSize -> 5 72]], 
      Dynamic[Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[
          First@Plot3D[funs[[n]], {x, y} \[Element] bdr, Axes -> None,
             AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], 
          ScalingTransform[{1, 1, Dynamic@Cos[t]}, {6, 6, 0}]]}, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}, {-1, 1}}, 
        BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}, ImageSize -> 5 72, 
        ViewPoint -> {-6, -20, 20}]], \[SpanFromLeft]}
     }]
   
   , {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
  Initialization :> (pts = 
     Table[{6, 6} + 3 {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
       2 \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]/10, 2 \[Pi]/10}];
    calculate[] := (bdr = Polygon@pts;
      {vals, funs} = 
       NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]}, 
        u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bdr, 6];);
    calculate[];)]
```

[image]

And make Mma to the full screen. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know all the settings in the original question, so here only a start point,in order to make the animation faster.( By remove `{x, y} ∈ bdr`, using `Evaluate` and decreasing the `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints`, only use `Manipulate` etc.)

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{vals, funs},
  {vals, funs} = 
   NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
    u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Polygon@pts, n]; 
  ContourPlot[funs[[n]], {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}, Axes -> None, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 20, PlotRange -> Full, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[f, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][f]], 
   ImageSize -> Medium, BoundaryStyle -> Thick]], {{pts, pts0}, 
  Locator}, 
 Initialization :> {pts0 = CirclePoints[{6, 6}, {3, 2 π/10}, 10], 
   n = 6}]
```

[image]