# Manipulate, TabView, and Histograms. Can they all be combined?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, histograms, charts

[I previously received assistance here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164596/5478) in constructing a `Manipulate` image that allows me to overlay plots of different data sets and toggle them on and off as needed, as shown below.

[image]

Since then, I have used `TabView` in an attempt to do a similar process with histograms, except with a total of 6 plots per 1 data set. Examples are shown below.

[image]

[image]

Each data set has a tab, with each tab having 2 sub-tabs containing different representations of the data as well as some statistics about the data. This seemed to be a very clean solution to the problem of not being able to work with `BarChart` and `Histogram` nicely in `Manipulate` in my few attempts.

However, I'm now looking to emulate the functionality of the `Manipulate` plot (figure 1) with the `Histogram/BarChart` plots (figures 2,3).

Is it possible to add another layer to the `TabView` to allow the combination of data sets (say I want Proposal 1 and Proposal 3 data at the same time, the histogram/bar chart views would represent the combined data)? Is it something that would need to be re-built from the ground up in `Manipulate`? If so, does anyone have any ideas? I moved to `TabView` for the second charts because I couldn't get `Manipulate` to work as intended in the first place...

I created a very stripped down version of the code with only the histogram calculations, but it is still obnoxiously long so I have paste it into a codepad.org link as plaintext here: http://codepad.org/kBxphb7U

The two sample data sets are the same but really I'm testing if they can be displayed separately as well as combined so I don't think that should be a problem. If the moderators would like, I can paste it here, but it truly is overly long...

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I'd do this. This is only a minimal example but enough for you to be able to convert the rest.

I'd make a function out of the procedure to generate plots/grid. A minimal example with one plot:

```
(*first run code from OP's link*)

λtimehistF[data_] := 
 BarChart[data, PlotRangePadding -> {{.1, 0.3}, {45, Max[data]/4}}, 
  ImageSize -> ImgSize, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Rotate[#, π/3], Above] &), 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["λ bins", Bold], 
    Style["Total time (ks)", Bold]}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Total Time vs. λ", Bold], 
  ChartStyle -> Darker[Green], BarSpacing -> Medium]
```

And I'd replace the outer `TabView` with a `TogglerBar` + `Dynamic[plotsgrid]`

```
Deploy@Panel@DynamicModule[
  {panes={1},switchFinished=False, data,coordinatesView,pitchView}
, Column[{
    DynamicWrapper[
      TogglerBar[
        Dynamic[panes, (panes=#/.{}->{1};switchFinished = False )&]
      , {1,2}
      ]
    , If[
        Not @ switchFinished
      , data = Join @@ (λtimedata /@ panes)
      ; coordinatesView =λtimehistF[data]
      ; switchFinished=True
      ]
    , SynchronousUpdating->False
    , TrackedSymbols:>{switchFinished}
    ]
  , Panel@TabView[{
      "Coordinate View"-> Dynamic[
        If[ 
          Not@switchFinished
        , Pane[ProgressIndicator[Appearance->"Percolate"]
          , ImgSize{1,1/GoldenRatio}
          , Alignment->Center
          ]
        , coordinatesView
        ]
      , TrackedSymbols:>{coordinatesView,switchFinished}
      ]
    , "Pitch View"->"you can do an analogous thing here too"
    }, ImageSize->All]
  }]
, UnsavedVariables:>{data,coordinatesView,pitchView}
]
```

[image]

`DynamicWrapper` is used to make a queued controller from `TogglerBar`, see: [How to Initiate a queued evaluation from a Dynamic GUI without using a Button](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19174/5478)

Comment: As usual, I really appreciate your elegant solution. I've spent some time looking over this and I genuinely would never have gotten to this solution with my working knowledge of mathematica. Thank you so much!