# How to solve 'graphics directive' issue?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

This is my code (I'm trying to graphically show the L'Hopital approximation of an isoelastic function):

```
p1 = Plot[Log[x],{x, 1, 20}]
p2 = Manipulate[Plot[x^(1-a)/(1-a),{x, 1, 20}], {a,0,1}]
Show[p1,p2]
```

I get the following error:

```
Coordinate Skeleton[1] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

How do I fix this? I've been trying a number of different solutions but they don't seem to work (apologies for the silly question - new to Mathematica).

Comment: `Show` can't combine `Graphics` and `Manipulate`, you can use `Manipulate[Show[plots...],..]`. You can use this trick to not recalculate 'static' `Log` plot: [148405](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148405/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I tried that and i'm still getting an error. What should my code be, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to combine both plots with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{Log[x], x^(1 - a)/(1 - a)}, {x, 1, 20}], {a, 0, 0.999}]
```

[image]