# How prevent nested OpenerView collapsing back to initial closed state when innermost contents change

Tags: gui-construction

Very simple example:

```
Manipulate[
  OpenerView[{
   "parent",
   OpenerView[{nested,doOption}]
  }],
  {{doOption, False,"Option:"}, {False,True}, Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> True}
 ]
```

If you open the outer parent then inner nested OpenerView, then click on the doOption toggle checkbox, the OpenerViews collapse.

[image]

Comment: `OpenerView[{nested, Dynamic@doOption}]` see this [148405](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148405/5478) or look around for 'nesting dynamic' concept.

Comment: @Kuba Thx, works for the simple case as shown. If you add as an answer I'll accept it for the simple case shown. Having some trouble applying it with some more complicated cases, but I'll need to raise another ticket with more specific cases and code examples for that.